# Impersonating UNIX User and update environment variables

Tags: c#, linux, mono, environment-variables, impersonation

I'm working on a Service with mono, that is started as privileged user and impersonating a non-privileged user for security reasons. The service often impersonates a user to run an external process and then switching back. But the external processes need the user-specific environment variables (like "$HOME") which are not changed by the User Impersonation.

That's the code i use to Impersonate an User:

```
WindowsIdentity tmpIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(user);
using(WindowsImpersonationContext tmpContext = tmpIdentity.Impersonate()) {
    //run process here
}
```

I also tried to run the following code before spawning the process but without impact:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HOME",Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`
does not change after/while the Impersonation

Is there a way to update the Environment Variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that environment variables are created for the process during it's invocation. Since an impersonation simply fakes another user by switching the user [Access Token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the environment variables won't be affected by this change. Thus the method `System.GetEnvironmentVariable(String)` will continues to return the *original* environment variables. Therefor updating the environment variables is something that you will have to do yourself.

Here might be some ways out of this :

- Once impersonated, create a new process responsible to get the environment variables
- Parse OS resources to get the values yourself (registery, /etc/passwd, etc)
- If you know exactly which users are going to be impersonated, you can use a config file

Comment: Yeah, I feared that I have to do it that way. I'll just let the user create a list then. Thanks!